# Why is matplotlib ignoring my rcParams settings?

Tags: matplotlib

In jupyter notebooks recently, I have had matplotlib ignore the `rcParams`.  For example, I will set `pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 8)`, then find that all plots come out with size `(6,4)`.  Generally, if I make a plot with some features (not a blank canvas), then set `rcParams` again, the settings stick.

This example shows the settings not sticking until the second time I create a figure:

```py
pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,8)
print(pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'])
pl.rcParams['font.size'] = 16

pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,8)
fig = pl.figure()
pl.draw()
ax = fig.gca()
print(fig.get_size_inches())
pl.close(fig.number)

pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,8)
fig = pl.figure()
pl.draw()
ax = fig.gca()
print(fig.get_size_inches())
pl.close(fig.number)
```

result:

```
[10.0, 8.0]
[6. 4.]
[10.  8.]
```

This behavior has only begun recently, so I suspect it's a change in matplotlib, but I can't pin it down.  I'm using matplotlib 3.5.2.

Comment: I ran your code in my environment. All had the same result. My environment has the following as likely related modules: `matplotlib:3.5.3, jupyterlab:3.4.6,notebook:6.4.12`

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer to this question now, though I still don't understand the origin and will accept a better answer.

If I run

```py
%matplotlib inline
```

before setting the rcparams, they "stick", while if I don't specify the backend first, the rcparams are re-set to the defaults upon the first instance of figure creation.